# Why can I only log in with firefox?

Tags: 7

I have an install of D7.9 that I can only access the admin tools with firefox. If I use IE, Chrome or Safari, I get "You Are Not Authorized to Access this Page" when I go to www.example.com/user and login.

Funny enough, if I try IE in compatibility mode it works fine, AND, if I try a different computer it works fine.

I've tried clearing all browser data, cookies, etc and it still won't jive..

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "admin tools"?

Comment: If you're using Secure Pages module, disable it as it has some problems.

Answer (score 2):

1. Login with Firefox.
2. While logged in on Firefox, open a separate window to www.example.com/user in Internet Explorer and try to log in.
3. If it fails, got back to the logged in session on Firefox and navigate to the Drupal Watchdog. See if any error appears.
4. Locate your PHP error logs, and see if they logged in any errors.
5. Edit your question and post any errors that you see.
6. ...
7. Profit!

I feel this is a somewhat ambiguous error that could be being caused by almost anything, and there will be no way that anyone here is going to be able to psychically log in to to your server and figure out what exactly is causing that, without a more descriptive question. Checking what are your current watchdog/PHP errors is probably the best thing that you can do at the moment.